# proxy_pass a domain that is protected with cloudflare

Tags: nginx, proxypass, cloudflare

Hello I wondered if it is possible to proxy_pass a domain that is protected with cloudflare in nginx?

I tried the following:

```
location / {
proxy_pass https://domainthatisprotectedwithcloudflare.net;
}
```

And I only get back a 502 Bad Gateway error on my nginx, direct IP works fine.

Answer (score 0):

If you control the domain, yes. You can [exempt your nginx server's IP from the DDOS protection](https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/articles/217074967-Configuring-IP-Access-Rules). If you *don't* control the domain, no (barring asking the domain's admins to do an exemption if you've got a legit use and they're friendly) - CloudFlare's protection does a variety of checks to detect if a real browser is accessing it, which your nginx install won't pass.

Comment: Thanks this is exactly what I was looking for!

Comment: This is not correct. Cloudflare doesn't necessarily ban non-browsers from visiting the site. It tries to detect *attacks* and mitigate them. E.g. many Cloudflare-protected sites are designed to be accessed via APIs from non-browser clients (or third-party servers). Moreover, if @AshratMughdi were being blocked by Cloudflare, the error would likely not be 502 Bad Gateway, it would be a Cloudflare-branded error. There is probably a configuration problem here.

Comment: Yeah I think so too, I tried to whitelist my IP to test this and after trying for many times I couldnt achieve a satisfying result, sadly.